# Facebook Graph API GET Request HTML / PHP

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I wanna make a Graph API HTTP Get Request via PHP, to get informations from Facebook. My Skript get the right informations but only some Hours and then the access token is invalid.

Does somebody know a solution for this ?

```
$fb_page_id = "*****";
$access_token= "*****";
$fields="id,name,description,place,timezone,start_time,cover";

$json_link = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/507029422815272?access_token={$access_token}";

$json = file_get_contents($json_link);
$obj = json_decode($json, true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);

print_r ($obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

The short-lived access token you seem to receive is normally valid for 2 hours. It can be exchanged to a long-lived access token via a Graph API call:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension

Sample call:

```
GET /oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token
    &client_id={app-id}
    &client_secret={app-secret}
    &fb_exchange_token={short-lived-token}
```